# Stubborn White Space at Top of Page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Simple problem but can't seem to find a functional solution. There's a finger-width white space at the top of the page that doesn't have anything highlighted under inspect.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 45px;
  left: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #1b1b1b;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: left 0.4s ease;
}

.btn.click {
  left: 260px;
}

.btn span {
  color: rgb(3, 3, 3);
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 45px;
}

.btn.click span:before {
  content: '\f00d';
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 225px;
  height: 100%;
  left: -225px;
  background: #1b1b1b;
  transition: left 0.4s ease;
}

.sidebar.show {
  left: 0px;
}

.sidebar .text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 65px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #1e1e1e;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

nav ul {
  background: #1b1b1b;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  line-height: 60px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

nav ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}

nav ul li a {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
}

nav ul li.active a {
  color: cyan;
  background: #1e1e1e;
  border-left-color: cyan;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #1e1e1e;
}

nav ul ul {
  position: static;
  display: none;
}

nav ul .feat-show.show {
  display: block;
}

nav ul .serv-show.show1 {
  display: block;
}

nav ul ul li {
  line-height: 42px;
  border-top: none;
}

nav ul ul li a {
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #e6e6e6;
  padding-left: 80px;
}

nav ul li.active ul li a {
  color: #e6e6e6;
  background: #1b1b1b;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}

nav ul ul li a:hover {
  color: cyan!important;
  background: #1e1e1e!important;
}

nav ul li a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 22px;
  color: black;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
}

nav ul li a span.rotate {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-180deg);
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #202020;
  z-index: -1;
  text-align: center;
}

.content .header {
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.content p {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

html {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>PeePoo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="btn">
    <span class="fas fa-bars"></span>
  </div>
  <nav class="sidebar">
    <div class="text">
      Side Menu
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="feat-btn">Features
             <span class="fas fa-caret-down first"></span>
             </a>
        <ul class="feat-show">
          <li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Elements</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="serv-btn">Services
             <span class="fas fa-caret-down second"></span>
             </a>
        <ul class="serv-show">
          <li><a href="#">App Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Shortcuts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <script>
    $('.btn').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("click");
      $('.sidebar').toggleClass("show");
    });
    $('.feat-btn').click(function() {
      $('nav ul .feat-show').toggleClass("show");
      $('nav ul .first').toggleClass("rotate");
    });
    $('.serv-btn').click(function() {
      $('nav ul .serv-show').toggleClass("show1");
      $('nav ul .second').toggleClass("rotate");
    });
    $('nav ul li').click(function() {
      $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    });
  </script>
</body>

<body>
  <h2 class="text-center my-5">The Website of Truth</h2>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center role=" columnheader ">The Code of Justinian, Book 1 Part 1</div>

        <div class="container ">

            <div class="justify-content-center ">  1. The Emperors Gratian, Valentinian, and Theodosius to the People of the City of Constantinople.

        We desire that all peoples subject to Our benign Empire shall live under the same religion that the Divine Peter, the Apostle, gave to the Romans, and which the said religion declares was introduced by himself, and which it is well known that the Pontiff Damasus, and Peter, Bishop of Alexandria, a man of apostolic sanctity, embraced; that is to say, in accordance with the rules of apostolic discipline and the evangelical doctrine, we should believe that the Father, Son, and Holy Spirit constitute a single Deity, endowed with equal majesty, and united in the Holy Trinity.
        
        (1) We order all those who follow this law to assume the name of Catholic Christians, and considering others as demented and insane, We order that they shall bear the infamy of heresy; and when the Divine vengeance which they merit has been appeased, they shall afterwards be punished in accordance with Our resentment, which we have acquired from the judgment of Heaven.
        
        Dated at Thessalonica, on the third of the Kalends of March, during the Consulate of Gratian, Consul for the fifth time, and Theodosius.
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Tried a bunch of things listed on google under the google search "white space at top of page bootstrap" with no luck. Still very new so simple explanations much appreciated <3

Comment: You have two body tags.

Comment: You have two body elements, which is invalid HTML, and you have a stray quotation mark which is obvious in the snippet editor and breaks things. Please fix up your markup. A good editor will help.

Comment: The page suffers multiple problems.  The html doesn't follow the Bootstrap documentation or examples.  And then a layer of custom css and javascript is added on top in an apparent effort to fix the broken markup. And why is it using a custom "sidebar" when Bootstrap 5 has a component that does this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `.btn` has a top position of 45px therefore the rest of the content align itself to it as it is your first relatively positioned element.

Try adding `top: 0;` to your `.sidebar` so that it aligns with the top of the document independently of your button top position and you'll see this space disappear.

Please note that for this fix to work you'll first have to fix a few issues in your markup as mentioned in various comments (only one body tag and ending double quote missing after `<div class="d-flex justify-content-center`).